# Disabled no funciona Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código para desbloquear un botón , pero no funciona, ***Cual es el error?, que significa que el error solo me aparezca en la consola de google chrome y no en los errores por ejemplo de liveweave.com?***

***ERROR:***

> uParty is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="partyCode" placeholder="Party code" type="text" disabled>
  <input onclick="uParty()" type="button" id="uParty" value="Unirse a party">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function uParty() {
        document.getElementById('partyCode').disabled = false;
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dependiendo el navegador que uses, deberias usar la consola javascript para ver los errores. Si no, estás a ciegas. En Chrome, por ejemplo, con `Ctrl-Shift-J`. ASí verías que te falta cerrar  la llave de la primer línea.

Comment: Eso no afecta,,

Comment: Sí que "afecta". Es un error. Que no alcance a solucionar el problema, es porque tienes otro error. Mira la consola.

Comment: Si es un error, pero no afecta la funcionalidad, me refiero a que ese no es el error principal y la consola por ejemplo de liveweave, no me da ningún error.

Comment: Es mucho trabajo copiar ese codigo html a un archivo y abrirlo en Chrome? es lo que deberías estar haciendo todo el tiempo si estás programando en Javascript.

Comment: reeditado leonbloy

Comment: Cómo se supone que debe funcionar? Qué se supone que quieres que haga la funcion `uParty()` habilitar el botón o deshabilitarlo? Por otro lado, quieres usar Jquery o no? Estás usando Jquery pero estás programando como si no lo usaras. Decidete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende si quieres usar  Jquery o Javascript "pelado"; estás mezclando las dos alternativas.

En Javascript "pelado" sería:

```js
function habilitar() {
          document.getElementById('partyCode').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="partyCode" placeholder="Party code" type="text" disabled>
<input type="button" id="uParty" value="Unirse a party" onclick="habilitar()">
```

Con Jquery sería así:

```js
$("#uParty").click( function() {
   $("#partyCode").prop('disabled', false);
 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="partyCode" placeholder="Party code" type="text" disabled>
<input type="button" id="uParty" value="Unirse a party" >
```

Desde ya, es importante que entiendas qué ocurre en cada caso...

Por cierto, tu código original simplemente anda si sacas la funcion fuera de todo ese bloque de inicializacion jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="partyCode" placeholder="Party code" type="text" disabled>
<input onclick="uParty()" type="button" id="uParty" value="Unirse a party">
<script>
 function uParty() {
            document.getElementById('partyCode').disabled = false;
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tu codigo original, lo que estaba haciendo era, al momento de estar `ready` la página, correr una cierta función (anónima) la cual sólo declaraba una función `uParty` (y recuerda que declarar una función en Javascript es como instanciar un objeto). Pero esa función `uParty` se declaraba/instanciaba como un objeto local de la función anónima (y no se invocaba ni se asignaba ni nada), por lo que al terminarse de ejecutar la función anónima, no quedaban rastros de `uParty`. Tú en cambio querías que `uParty` quedara disponible en el entorno global (que en Javascript hosteado en página web corresponde al objeto `window`). Por lo tanto, podrías si quieres hacer esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.uParty =  function () {
            document.getElementById('partyCode').disabled = false;
      }
   });
```

Pero sería algo retorcido, y nada necesario.

Comment: Losé el problema es que me da el error: uParty is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick  , por eso creí agregarle el document.ready para que funcionase apenas se carga

Comment: Mi problema es que la función está dentro de un IIFE

Answer (score 1):

Les comparto un código que me pasaron muy bueno ya lo probe y si habilita y desabilita un input

cuando nfactura es mi input y caja es mi combox

```
<script >

//con esta funcion haces que el combox habilite un text

var input = document.getElementById('nfactura');

function carg(elemento) {
  d = caja.value;

  if(d == "cf"){
    nfactura.disabled = false;

  }else{
    nfactura.disabled = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

en el combox

```
  <select id="caja" name="caja" onchange="carg(this);" >
      <option value="*">selecciona los datos</option>
      <option value="sf" >sin factura</option>
      <option value="cf" >con factura</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambié varias cosas:

- Puse la etiqueta `<script></script>` en `<head></head>`.
- Quité la función `uParty` de `$(document).ready(function(){}`, quedando suelta.
- La función `getElementById`, en mi opinión, no sirve de nada, ya que se puede llamar directamente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function uParty() {
    partyCode.disabled=false
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="partyCode" placeholder="Party code" type="text" disabled>
    <input onclick="uParty()" type="button" id="uParty" value="Unirse a party">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo de omitir `getElementById` aprovechando que los elementos con id se ven como atributos del objeto `window` funciona pero es [fuertemente desaconsejado](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: @leonbloy Es interesante, no sabía. Solo hay que tener cuidado que no choquen los nombres entre el id y una variable global.